Error to access add record template from admin site using Jazzmin template
I got this error when I try to use jazzmin template in my django project.
This error occured only when I try to access the add record template from admin site
But when I use default django admin template all things right.
I ge
t this error :
    <div class="form-group{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if not line.has_visible_field %} hidden{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">


the issue for me also. It was working without any problems a week ago in my other projects. Smth gotta be wrong with a new version of Django or Python

Add filter in /.venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/jazzmin/templatetags/jazzmin.py
@register.filter(name="length_is")
def length_is(value: Any, length: str | int) -> bool:
    return len(value) == int(length)

